# Java out of memory: increase heap space?

Tags: java, r, heap-memory, topic-modeling

This seems to be a common issue, however the existing solutions didn't work for me. 
I am trying to perform topic modeling in R with the help of the mallet package.
The corpus consists of forum comments and is app. 50 MB large. It is divided in 41.975 files.

Here's my script:

```
documents_65 <- mallet.read.dir("~/20170315_F65/tm")  

# Loading corpus and stopwords
mallet.instances <- mallet.import(id.array = documents_65$id, 
                                  text.array = documents_65$text,
                              "~/stopwords.txt", 
                              token.regexp = "\\p{L}[\\p{L}\\p{P}]+\\p{L}")
topic.model <- MalletLDA(num.topics = 1000)
topic.model$loadDocuments(mallet.instances)
vocabulary <- topic.model$getVocabulary()
word.freqs <- mallet.word.freqs(topic.model)
topic.model$setAlphaOptimization(10, 30)
topic.model$train(1000)
topic.model$maximize(10)
doc.topics <- mallet.doc.topics(topic.model, smoothed=T,
                            normalized=T)
```

After this I get the error:

```
Error in .jcall(wrapper, "[D", "flat_double") : 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

As many have suggested, I tried

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1000m")
```

After that I tried the mallet.doc.topics command again and got the same error. I tried to assign the heap space in the Control Panel (as suggested here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-D24vnuUMM).

I also tried

```
gc()
```

Output:

```
           used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells  2407281 128.6    6619081 353.5  7415161 396.1
Vcells 32395876 247.2   48628929 371.1 48628929 371.1
```

as well as assigning more heap space through the command line with this:

```
java -Xmx2048m
```

I even tried to peak into the assigned memory with the XLConnect-package and the following commands:

```
xlcMemoryReport ()
```

Output:

```
Amount of free memory in the Java Virtual Machine (JVM):  308.0197 MB

xlcFreeMemory()


.jcall(.jnew("java/lang/Runtime"), "J", "totalMemory")
.jcall(.jnew("java/lang/Runtime"), "J", "maxMemory")
```

I hope I am not missing something really basic. I can imagine that my corpus is hard to handle and requires a lot of memory (mostly because of the large amount of files).

UPDATE: 
I couldn't resolve this issue in R and switched to mallet directly. There I found the batch file with specs for mallet, in which one could see that the java memory allotted to mallet was limited to 1 GB. Since my corpus was around 1.3 GB it wasn't possible at all to load it into Mallet. In the batch file I could easily change this and kept working with mallet directly.

I don't know, if it possible to access the batch file from R.

Comment: No, it's Windows 10.

Comment: UPD: reinstalled the JDK version and everything started working a lot faster. It seemed to be the main problem. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 2):

We have to assume you're running a 64 bit JVM. The max heap you can allocate to a 32 bit JVM is 1.6 GB.

Are you running JDK 1.8?  You should be. Perm gen is gone, replaced by managed meta space.

Maybe you can profile the app using [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io).

Comment: I am running the Java Version 1.8.0_121 and a 64 bit JVM.

Comment: The tools may differ across OS platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Run Java with the command-line option `-Xmx`, which sets the maximum size of the heap.

[Click Here to see Details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#nonstandard)

I Hope its helpful for you!